# Turn on/off MySQL events using php or codeigniter functions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have created a MySQL event that executes once a month to archive some tables in my database for my web app.

The problem is that I need a PHP function to manually turn that event on or off, I'm also using Codeigniter for my framework, so if it can be done using Codeigniter's functions, it would be much better.

Comment: How did you do this periodic refresh, Cron job ?

Comment: I jut created an event schedule in my database, a stored proc that executes once a month

Comment: Okay why don't you also create a 1 bit attribute in database `1` => `ON` and `0` => `OFF`. Then in the condition say if falg is equal to one and time to update, then update ?

Comment: Your solution could work, thank you very much Amir, will try your answer :)

Comment: No prob, if it worked please consider a `mark solved`. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 1 bit attribute in database `1` => `ON` and `0` => `OFF`. Then in the condition say if flag is equal to `1` AND `time to update`, then update.